Can the Froissart bound be improved?
The Froissart bound is a fundamental result in (axiomatic) quantum field theory, an introduction to which from Froissart himself can be found here.
Given a reaction of scalar particles $1 + 2 \rightarrow 3 + 4$, there exists a constant $C >0$ such that, denoting by $s$ the $1,2$ Mandelstam invariant, the associated total cross-section $\sigma_{\text{tot}}$ is bounded in the large $s$ limit by:
$$\sigma_{tot}(s) \underset{s \rightarrow + \infty}{\lesssim} c_0 (\log s)^2.$$
I'd like to know whether or not this bound can be improved. Some literature does exist on the subject, but it remains unclear to me, as:

Some authors say it is the case

https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.3564
https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.05754 (this paper considers the AdS version of the bound to get an improvement, but I am not so sure about how it carries to the flat space version which is the one above)
https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.5314


Some authors say it is not the case

https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.0680 (note that although the abstract says "yes", the answer by the author at the top of page 3 is definitely "no" !)
https://cds.cern.ch/record/136830/?ln=fr (if the bound can be saturated, then it is that it can't be improved without further assumptions)
https://academic.oup.com/ptp/article/45/6/1960/1877954



At this stage, I'd love it if an actual expert in axiomatic QFT / mathematical high energy physics could share an overview on the subject.
